# need help writing a query (restructuring the table)

Tags: mysql, sql, unpivot

I need to write a select statement that will rewrite the table in the following manner...  I'm not sure how to go about this using MySQL.

Example of table

```
user_id   date         a    b    c     
123456    2020-01-01   1    1    1
234567    2020-03-04   1    0    0
453576    2020-05-05   1    0    1
```

Desired result

```
user_id   date        results
123456    2020-01-01  a
123456    2020-01-01  b
123456    2020-01-01  c
234567    2020-03-04  a
453576    2020-05-05  a
453576    2020-05-05  c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL you can unpivot with `union all`, while filtering on `1` values:

```
select user_id, date, 'a' as result from mytable where a = 1
union all select user_id, date, 'b' from mytable where b = 1
union all select user_id, date, 'c' from mytable where c = 1
order by user_id, date, result
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large amount of data or your "table" is really a complex query (say a subquery or view), then unpivoting is usually faster with `cross join` than with `union all`:

```
select t.user_id, t.date, r.result
from t cross join
     (select 'a' as result union all
      select 'b' as result union all
      select 'c' as result 
     ) r
where (t.a = 1 and r.result = 'a') or
      (t.b = 1 and r.result = 'b') or
      (t.c = 1 and r.result = 'c') ;
```

For a single smallish table, performance probably doesn't matter.